# Ffmpeg Fps interpolation error

Tags: ffmpeg, fps

I wanted to change the frame rate of the video and found out about **minterpolate** filter feature in ffmpeg

So i tried to test it out and run a simple command.

> ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter "minterpolate='fps=60'" output.mp4

however i get this error massage.

```
Cannot connect video filter to audio input
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:2
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter:v "minterpolate=fps=60" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

`filter` is an option which is applied to all qualifying streams. If `-filter:v:2` is specified, it will be applied to the third video output stream. `-filter:v` will be applied to all video output streams, and `-filter` to all output streams (video, audio, subtitle) that are being processed.

Since `-filter` was specified in the OP's command, ffmpeg applied to audio streams as well, but `minterpolate` is a video-only filter.

Comment: Can you explain more to help the users